# HTML returns and lists all the entries, that are urls, in the database. But I don't know how to make it actual links

Tags: python, html, api

My html page returns urls that have been stored in the database through use of a for loop. But I don't Know how to make the url an actual working link. For example 'https://www.google.com/ is the first entry that is listed on the HTML page but when I click on it it leads nowhere'

This is the html for loop that will list the url entries

```
<tbody>
{% for website in websites %}
    <tr>
        <td>{!! app</td>
        <td><a href="{{website['website']}}">{{website['website']}}</a></td>
        <td><a href="/websites/edit?id={{website['id']}}">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

extra info if it is needed this is the backend of client side

```
def list_websites():
resp = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/websites')
websites = json.loads(resp.content)
return render_template('websites.html', websites=websites)
```

this is server side

```
def list_websites():
with SQL('data_web.db') as db:
    db.execute("SELECT * FROM websites")
    data = db.fetchall()
    db.commit()
return json.dumps(data)
```

If anyone can just shove me in the right direction here. I am new to API's and HTML and Python

Comment: NvM the program decided to work. It returns the pages

Comment: LOL it was my own stupidity holding me back